# Какой peer_id на стороне бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Почему при использовании peer_id в любом методе, с этим значением, пишет в ответе None.
К примеру, в messages.getConversationsById указываю нужный peer_id. В ответ: None

Comment: Предоставьте [example]

Answer (score 1):

Вк отписал бы вам нужную ошибку с кодом, т.е. у вас ошибка в коде (где нибудь может return не стоит)
Если вы уверены, что все правильно, просто зайдите через сообщения бота и в адресной строке просмотрите peer_id